# Big-integer Fibonacci sequence diverges at 36'th term: Project Euler #25

Tags: javascript, node.js, biginteger, fibonacci

So I am trying to solve project euler #25 via the big integer brute force method with [this module](https://github.com/peterolson/BigInteger.js). Everything seems to go properly until the 36'th term, which actually decreases. Then the terms increase as they should, and then decrease again; they never go over 10 million. I have also noticed the 36'th term has all digits correct except one as it is supposed to be 14930352 but I get 4930352 Could this be a problem with my code or a bug in the module?

```
var bigInt = require('big-integer');
var number = bigInt(1);
var last = bigInt(1);

for(i=0;i<50;i++){
  number = number.add(last);
  last = number.minus(last);
  console.log(number.toString());
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a bug in the library. If you use a tmp variable it works fine.

```
var bigInt = require('big-integer');
var number = bigInt(1);
var last = bigInt(1);

for(i=0;i<50;i++){
  //number = number.add(last);
  //last = number.minus(last);

  var tmp = number.add(last);
  last = number;
  number = tmp;
  console.log((i + 3) + ":" + number.toString());
}
```